# PHP % operator, what result should be returned?

Tags: php, modulus

$djs_all_num = mysql_num_rows($djs_all_db);
            while($djs_all = mysql_fetch_array( $djs_all_db )) {
            if ($djs_all_num % "2") {

With my if () statement, this should halve the amount of rows, and so in the else further on it should display the rest.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't halve anything.  It gives the remainder with 2 as divisor.  This will be 0 if even, 1 if odd.  So if `djs_all_num` is odd, it will enter the if statement.  You should write `2` instead.  Using the implicit conversion from string to int is confusing and unnecessary.

Note that this does not operate per-row, since the left operand is the total row count, not the row index.  To use a row index, do something like:

```
$row_ind = 0;
$djs_all_num = mysql_num_rows($djs_all_db);
        while($djs_all = mysql_fetch_array( $djs_all_db )) {
        if ($row_ind++ % 2) {
```

Comment: I'm never getting the else running, any idea why?

Comment: It doesn't actually halve everything, but it should "split" my rows into two groups.

Comment: @Sam, if your row count is always odd, the if will always run.  If you want to alternate between rows, you need to use a row index, not the row count.

Comment: So...how do I do this, I thought mysql_num_rows counted the number of rows.

Comment: It does; and the row count never changes, unless you execute a new query.  As I said, I think you you want a row index.  See my example code above.

Answer (score 1):

The % operator aka Modulus (edit)determines if there was a remainder(/edit). Used quite oftenly to determine odd / even rows.

So a 1 % 2 would equal <s>.5</s> 1 <s>(I think if my math is correct).</s>  2 % 2 = 0.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Sorry did some local testing and found out my statement was incorrect, modified to be correct.